# How can I perform bitwise AND with BLOBs?

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, blob

Is it somehow possible to perform bitwise AND with BLOB values?

(The background is to read single bits in long BLOBs).

Take this statement:

```
SELECT 'AFFE01';
```

It brings the String `AFFE01`.

```
SELECT UNHEX('AFFE01');
```

This brings a BLOB with the bytes `0xaf`, `0xfe` and `0x01`.

I can *substring* that BLOB:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UNHEX('AFFE01'),3,1);
```

That brings the BLOB `0x01`.

**How can I now get the last bit from that?**

Trying

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UNHEX('AFFE01'),3,1) & 1;
```

returns `0` and not `1`.

Comment: Your MySQL version? (Specifically: MySQL 8 or not).

Comment: It's older than MySQL 8. :-(